# Unset HTTP proxy option for svn using --config-option

Tags: macos, subversion

If a have a `~/.subversion/servers` file that looks like this:

```
[groups]
corporate-repo=*.repo.example.com

[corporate-repo]
http-proxy-host= www-proxy.example.com
http-proxy-port= 80
http-proxy-compression= no
ssl-client-cert-file=/path/to/cert.pfx
```

How can I use the `--config-option` switch to `svn` to unset the HTTP proxy option when connecting to myrepo.repo.example.com on a different network where the configured proxy server is not available.

This is on macOS, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Can't you use `http-proxy-exceptions = myrepo.repo.example.com` in your config?

Comment: @Freddy I want to know how to do it from the command - I'm not seeking to add an exception for a specific repo, but to prevent use of the proxy altogether. I've edited the question to explain.

Comment: I think the answer in [stackoverflow.com/questions/16649199](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649199) should do the trick using an empty value. Can't test it myself right now.

Comment: http-proxy-host="" doesn't work, unfortunately, neither does '' or leaving it empty after the =